# VB Control after click event completes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a problem with a click-event that deletes a series of controls. In stepping though the click event, everything works perfectly but other text box controls on the page are being blanked out (not deleted, just losing their text content). I've stepped through the code and found that everything is find going into the "End Sub" statement of the click event but the blanking out happens when the End Sub is executed. I'm attaching the click event but there's not much to see. Any ideas what's happening?

```
    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    CommonDelete(tbline.Text)
End Sub

    Public Sub CommonDelete(LineNum As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Dim lineFound As Boolean = False
    Dim LineInt As Integer = 0
    Dim VLength As String = " "
    Dim VLengthInt As Integer = 0

    topLine = 0
    bottomLine = 0

    VLength = arrTextVals.GetLength(1)
    VLengthInt = CInt(VLength)

    Try
        LineInt = CInt(LineNum)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The line you selected is invalid", "Drop Zone Error DL1:",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    For i = 1 To VLengthInt - 1
        If arrTextVals(1, i) = LineNum Then
            lineFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If lineFound <> True Then
        MessageBox.Show("The line you selected is invalid", "Drop Zone Error DL2:",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For j = i To VLengthInt - 2
        topLine = j
        bottomLine = j + 1
        SwitchRows()
    Next

    RemoveControl(arrTextVals(0, bottomLine))
    RemoveControl(arrTextVals(2, bottomLine))
    RemoveControl(arrTextVals(4, bottomLine))
    RemoveControl(arrTextVals(6, bottomLine))

    tbline.Text = " "

End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveControl(ControlName As String)
    Dim ctr As Control

    For Each ctr In Me.Controls

        If ctr.Name = ControlName Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(ctr)
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next ctr

End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably your `CommonDelete` method doesn't actually do what you think it does, but we can only speculate because you haven't provided us with that method.

Comment: Show the `CommonDelete` method.

Comment: Here is the CommonDelete method. Once the last statement is executed, the tbline.Text = " ", the method seems to have done everything it was supposed to.

Comment: Sorry - I tried to add the code but it takes me over the maximum character length. Is there a way around this? Using multiple postings seems a bit dirty.

Comment: Edit your original question to add the code.

Comment: Thanks Blackwood - done. Please remember that it's not the End Sub statement of the CommonDelete sub that's causing the problem - that executes with everything looking good. The code then moves back to the End Sub statement of the event handler and when that executes the text disappears.